# Extract element names and type from XSD schemas

Tags: python

I've got several schema definitions that I need to reconcile with a data model. I'm trying to extract the entity names, types and attribute names and types from these schema definitions with the Python ElemTree library, but finding it difficult to get the exact information out.

In my XSDs there are several of the below complex types.

I've been trying to use `[elem.tag for elem in root.iter()]` but it gives all the tags as well which I'm not interested in. I'm thinking XPath might be the way but I'm stuck.

Is there an easy way to just extract the name and type attributes?

```
<xsd:complexType name="EntityX_t">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="xyz" type="xxx:Entityx_t"/>
        <xsd:element name="subElement">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="subelement" type="SubElement_t" maxOccurs="2"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="elementRelationships" type="xxx:ElementRelationships_t" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>lorem ipsum...</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="notesSection" type="xxx:NotesSection_t" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="extension" type="abcExtension_t" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `XSD` is valid like this (with namespace and root):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:complexType name="EntityX_t">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="xyz" type="xxx:Entityx_t" />
      <xsd:element name="subElement">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="subelement" type="SubElement_t" maxOccurs="2" />
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="elementRelationships" type="xxx:ElementRelationships_t" minOccurs="0">
        <xsd:annotation>
          <xsd:documentation>lorem ipsum...</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="notesSection" type="xxx:NotesSection_t" minOccurs="0" />
      <xsd:element name="extension" type="abcExtension_t" minOccurs="0" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

you can parse it with `xml.etree.ElementTree`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

tree = ET.parse('L4zl0w.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

tags_list =[]
data = []
for elem in root.iter():
    row = elem.attrib
    tg = elem.tag
    #print(elem.text, elem.attrib)
    data.append(row)
    tags_list.append(tg)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['tag'] = pd.DataFrame(tags_list)
print(df.to_string())
```

Output:

```
                    name                        type maxOccurs minOccurs                                              tag
0                    NaN                         NaN       NaN       NaN         {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}schema
1              EntityX_t                         NaN       NaN       NaN    {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}complexType
2                    NaN                         NaN       NaN       NaN       {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}sequence
3                    xyz               xxx:Entityx_t       NaN       NaN        {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}element
4             subElement                         NaN       NaN       NaN        {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}element
5                    NaN                         NaN       NaN       NaN    {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}complexType
6                    NaN                         NaN       NaN       NaN       {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}sequence
7             subelement                SubElement_t         2       NaN        {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}element
8   elementRelationships  xxx:ElementRelationships_t       NaN         0        {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}element
9                    NaN                         NaN       NaN       NaN     {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}annotation
10                   NaN                         NaN       NaN       NaN  {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}documentation
11          notesSection          xxx:NotesSection_t       NaN         0        {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}element
12             extension              abcExtension_t       NaN         0        {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}element
```